# Android 2.3 AudioTrack issue(obtainbuffer timed out -- is cpu pegged?)

Tags: android, streaming, cpu, aac, audiotrack

I'm writing an audio streaming app that buffers AAC file chunks, decodes those chunks to PCM byte arrays, and writes the PCM audio data to AudioTrack.  Occasionally, I get the following error when I try to either skip to a different song, call AudioTrack.pause(), or AudioTrack.flush():

```
obtainbuffer timed out -- is cpu pegged?
```

And then what happens is that a split second of audio continues to play.  I've tried reading a set of AAC files from the sdcard and got the same result.   The behavior I'm expecting is that the audio stops immediately.  Does anyone know why this happens? I wonder if its an Audio latency issue with Android 2.3.

edit: The AAC audio contains an ADTS Header.  The header + audio payload constitute what I'm calling ADTSFrame.  These are fed to the decoder one frame at a time.  The resulting PCM byte array that gets returned from the C layer to the Java Layer gets fed to Android's AudioTrack API.

edit 2: I got my nexus 7 (Android 4.1 OS) today.  Loaded the same APP onto the device.  Didn't have any of these problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

it is highly possible about sample rate. one of your devices might be supporting the sample rate u used while the other could not. Please check it. I had the same issue, it was about sample rate. use 44.1kHz (44100) and try again please.